# How can I copy a column of cells in Excel, with VBA, until there is a blank and paste it into a new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

We have a spreadsheet from a client that consists of 150 odd tabs of the same daily work form.

In each work form, in the same positions, are a date in C4 and a list of tasks carried out starting in B10. The tasks carried out vary in a number of cells; some have 3 some have 8 etc. so a list.
[image: redacted sheet, partial]

I need to copy the tasks carried out into the database sheet, Column B, then copy the date from C4 (in the work sheet) into column A (of the database sheet), for each one of the tasks carried out.
If there are 5 tasks carried out copy the date to Column A 5 times.
Then do that for all the tabs, so it is in one list.

There is a gap below the list of tasks of 1 cell then more data, this is the same above. Not sure if End(xlUp) or End(xldown) would be usable.

Multiple tabs macro - the issue is it copies to each tab, not a single tab

```vb
Sub DateCLM()
    
    DateCLM Macro
    Date Column
    
    Dim xSh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xSh In Worksheets
        xSh.Select
        Call RunCode
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there data below the list of works (after the gap)? Does each worksheet contain only one list or several?

Comment: there is data below and above with a single cell gap i was thinking about using End(xlUp) or End(xldown) but with it being sandwiched between information im not sure if it will work.

Comment: The expected output to the Database worksheet shall include only the lines `1.0 Construction`, `2.0 Commissioning`, `3.0 another work`, etc, or also the lines `.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` are to be included?

Comment: Hey EEM thanks for the reply. Looking for the information within 1.0 Construction. so basically on each tab all the xxxxxxxxx parts in the Construction section. Basically, there are 120+ tabs with the same form on it.. looking to get the date on each from C4 and the different work carried out (in the example pic thats the xxxxxxx) all into one page, so it can be filtered and analysed more easily.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I copy a column of cells in excel, with VBA, until there is a
> blank and paste it into a new sheet?

Here is an algorithm I came up with years ago to solve this problem.

```
Create variables for the first and last cells in your range
Set the value of the first cell in the range, i.e. B10
Select the first cell in the range
While active cell is not empty
   select the next cell down
end while
select the range of cells between your two variables
---perform some action---
```

I don't have access to the original file, nor have I used VBA for years, but I've given it a go. Hopefully this will give you a help in the right direction?

```
Sub selectRange()

    'Create variables for the first and last cells in your range
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range
    
    'Set the value of the first cell in the range, i.e. B10
    firstCell = Range("B10")
    
    'Select the first cell in the range
    firstCell.Select
    firstCell.Activate
    
    'Loop while cell is empty
    While Not ActiveCell = ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Wend
    
    'After empty cell is found, activate last non-empty cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
    lastCell = ActiveCell
    
    'Select the range of cells between your two variables
    ActiveSheet.Range(firstCell, lastCell).Select
    
    '---perform some action--- 
End Sub
```

Comment: really appreciate the help.. currently getting an "object variable or With block variable not set" for firstCell = Range("B10")

Answer (score 0):

### Copy From Multiple Worksheets

- It is assumed that the data is consistent:

  - `Database` is a worksheet in the same workbook as the worksheets to be processed,
  - all dates are in cell `C4` and are actual dates,
  - all other data is located from cell `B10` to before (above) the first blank cell below.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyFromMultipleWorksheets()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Database"
    Const wsCell As String = "A2"
    Const datesCell As String = "C4"
    Const worksFirstCell As String = "B10"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    
    ' Define Arrays.
    Dim Works As Variant: ReDim Works(1 To wsCount - 1)
    Dim Dates() As Date: ReDim Dates(1 To wsCount - 1)
    Dim RowsCount() As Long: ReDim RowsCount(1 To wsCount - 1)
    Dim OneValue As Variant: ReDim OneValue(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range ' Source Range
    Dim rCount As Long ' Rows Count
    Dim tRows As Long ' Total Rows (for Data Array)
    Dim n As Long ' Worksheets, Dates, Works Arrays, RowCounts Counter
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsName Then
            ' Define Works Range.
            With ws.Range(worksFirstCell)
                Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
                Set rg = rg.Find("", rg.Cells(rg.Rows.Count), xlFormulas)
                Debug.Print rg.Address
                Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row)
            End With
            ' Count, write date and count some more.
            n = n + 1
            Dates(n) = ws.Range(datesCell).Value
            rCount = rg.Rows.Count
            RowsCount(n) = rCount
            tRows = tRows + rCount
            ' Write values from Works Range to current array of Works Array.
            If rCount > 1 Then
                Works(n) = rg.Value
            Else
                Works(n) = OneValue: Works(n)(1, 1) = rg.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Write values from arrays of Works Array to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To tRows, 1 To 2)
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For n = 1 To n
        For i = 1 To RowsCount(n)
            k = k + 1
            Data(k, 1) = Dates(n)
            Data(k, 2) = Works(n)(i, 1)
        Next i
    Next n
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(wsCell).Resize(, 2)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(k).Value = Data
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
  
End Sub
```

Comment: I've only now seen the image. The code should get only `Construction` and the few rows below it. Test it and report with some clarifications what should be corrected.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!, when I run the code I get an application-defined or object-defined error against this Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row)

Comment: What are the values of the variables when the error occurs? e.g. `worksFirstCell`, `n`, `.Row`, `rg.Address` in the immediate window (`CTRL+G`) etc. Hover over them, and a value may appear. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LElw_TJTv1V2ZpncC2gbaMALfYwRWv-O/view?usp=sharing) to my file on `Google Drive`.It should shed a light on how I imagined the data.

Comment: in the immediate window its $B$10

Comment: It should mean that the value in `B10` (Last Cell) is blank on whatever sheet the code was. The first cell is `B10` so `Resize` fails because `10 - 10 = 0` (it has to be at least 1).

Comment: Your google drive file is right, in that its a database sheet to collect all the information from the subsequent sheets... not sure what to do. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: could it because of merged cells?

Comment: If you mean that cells `B10, B11...` are merged, I just tried by merging them with the adjacent cells and the code still works. But you should clarify what you exactly want. EEM is also asking you to clarify in **your** comments. He will surely know what to do (you shouldn't rely on one contributor to be able to help you).

Comment: Thanks a lot @VBasic2008 I appreciate all the help. Basically, we have 120+ tabs of the same work form. We want to be able to take the date from each and the construction section (all the xxxxs in section 1 of the example picture) and consolidate it all on one sheet so we can filter and analyse it all more efficiently.

Comment: Hi there @VBasic2008. It seems that the reason for the error in this line `Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row)` is because the “list of works” below the `1.0 Construction` line is empty. Suggest to check for the value 0 and move to the next worksheet.